# Filtering two arrays for matching values into new array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to match two arrays and extract the matching values into a new array while keeping it in the same order as the second array. For example:

```
let strArr1 = ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']; 
let strArr2 = ['p','p','a','e', 'l', 'l', 'k'];
let newArr = [];
// Wanted output: ['p', 'p', 'a', 'e', 'l']
```

So what I'm trying to do here is remove the extra characters in the second array. The code I've come up with so far:

```
for (let i=0; i < strArr1.length; i++){
for (let j=0; j < strArr2.length; j++){
if (strArr1[i]==strArr2[j]){
  newArr.push(strArr2[i])
  }
 }
}
```

For some reason, the output becomes:

```
['p', 'p', 'p', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'l']
```

I've also tried the filter method. It's closer to the results I want.

```
const newArr = strArr2.filter(value => strArr1.includes(value));
```

But the output becomes:

```
['p', 'p', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'l']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newArr = strArr2.filter(value => strArr1.includes(value) && arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1));
```

This works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
strArr1 = strArr1.reduce((acc, v)=> ({ ...acc, [v]: (acc[v] ? (++acc[v]) : 1) }), {})
strArr2.filter(v => !!(strArr1[v]--)  )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code though, you are pushing strArr2[i] in the `newArr` although, you used `j` to iterate over strArr2. And when you find a match to push into `newArr`, you need to break the loop and move to the next element in `strArr2`.

In order to keep the order in strArr2 you need to change the order of the for loop,

```
for (let i=0; i < strArr2.length; i++){
  for (let j=0; j < strArr1.length; j++){
     if (strArr1[j]==strArr2[i]){
        newArr.push(strArr2[i])
        j += strArr1.length;
     }
  }
}
```

The complexity is O(n^2) You can optimize the code by doing the following,

```js
let strArr1 = ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']; 
let strArr2 = ['p','p','a','e', 'l', 'l', 'k'];
let newArr = [];
// Wanted output: ['p', 'p', 'a', 'e', 'l']

newArr = strArr2.filter(item => strArr1.includes(item));

console.log(newArr);
```

`['p', 'p', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'l']` is correct output as there is two `l` in the `strArr2`.

If you want to match each value once, you can remove the value from `strArr1` after finding a match.

```js
let strArr1 = ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']; 
let strArr2 = ['p','p','a','e', 'l', 'l', 'k'];
let newArr = [];
console.log('abc');

newArr = strArr2.reduce((prev, curr) => {

            if(strArr1.includes(curr)) {
               prev.push(curr);
               strArr1.splice(strArr1.indexOf(curr), 1);
            }
            return prev;
         }, []);
         
console.log(newArr);
```